# AngularJS: $timeout CSS fixer doesn't run on page load

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, event-binding

I'm having a devil of a time trying to get a manual HTML layout fixer to run consistently when a route is first loaded. (I'm using Bootstrap, but the client's layout is an unconventional grid.) I've done a lot of searching and tried several fixes. Watching `$viewContentLoaded` didn't work. Using `angular.element(document).ready()` was a no-go. Using a standard jQuery `$(document).ready()` didn't work. `ng-init` didn't work. Many people suggested using the `$timeout` service without a specified delay, which supposedly runs after the view is loaded. It's been at least sometimes successful.

Here's the chunk in my controller:

```
var w = angular.element($window);
var dimensionFixer = function () {
    angular.element('#home-bottom').css("height", angular.element('#top').height());
    angular.element('#logo-box').css("height", angular.element('#home-top-left').height() - angular.element("#home-top-right-partial").height() - 15);
};
w.bind('resize', dimensionFixer);
$timeout(dimensionFixer);
```

Sometimes it works. Sometimes it doesn't. I've also tried combining `$viewContentLoaded` and `$timeout`. It always works on resize. Has `$timeout` or browser functionality changed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 : Enclose the element resize within timeout. Your revived code would be

> var w = angular.element($window); 
>   $timeout(function(){
>   var dimensionFixer = function ({ angular.element('#home-bottom').css("height", angular.element('#top').height()); angular.element('#logo-box').css("height", angular.element('#home-top-left').height() - angular.element("#home-top-right-partial").height() - 15); };
>   w.bind('resize', dimensionFixer);
>   })

Option 2 : Explicitly calling `$scope.$apply` which updates the DOM

Comment: Option 1 didn't fix it. It still has to be resized to line up right. Where do you mean for me to call `$scope.$apply()`? The place I tried gave me the old inprog error.

Edit: Added `dimensionFixer();` after the line binding the function to the resize event. Seems to be working, so thanks!

Edit 2: Nope, still not always working. :(